# Lyx does not appear in "Open with..." list, Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, unity, lyx

I installed Lyx on Ubuntu 18.04 with Unity desktop. The program  does not appear on the list of "Open with Other Application", and .lyx files can't be opened by click. Some solutions on the web suggest to edit Exec field in the corresponding .desktop file. My lyx.desktop file is given below.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=LyX
GenericName=Document Processor
Comment=High level LaTeX frontend
Keywords=WYSIWYG;WYSIWYM;TeX;LaTeX;GUI;frontend;editor;
Exec=lyx %F
TryExec=lyx
Icon=lyx
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Lyx
Terminal=false
Categories=Office;WordProcessor;Qt;
MimeType=text/x-lyx;application/x-lyx;
```

Comment: Welcome on U&L! You may need to run `sudo update-desktop-database` to update the cache that tells how MIME types are handled by desktop files (but I'm not on Ubuntu, I can't be sure).

Answer (score 0):

The command line method worked for me; see https://askubuntu.com/questions/491378/add-application-to-open-with-list
The application is still not in the "Open with..." list, but .lyx files
are opened automatically...